# C# charting: How to not draw an empty point in stacked area chart

Tags: c#, charts, mschart, stacked-area-chart

How can I not draw an empty point in C# charting library? I do not want the last empty point with 0 value for 11/10 to be drawn in the chart, but inspite of setting it as Empty point it is drawn with a value of 0.

Check out the chart here.

[image]

Here's the code:

```cs
void Main()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1 = new Chart();
    ChartArea chartArea1 = new ChartArea("foobar");
    chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
    chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);

    chart1.Name = "chart1";
    chart1.Palette = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartColorPalette.Fire;     
    Series series1 = new Series("seriesfoo")
     {
         XValueType = ChartValueType.Date,
        ChartArea = "ChartArea1",
        ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedArea,
        Legend = "Legend1",
        Name = "MyGraph",
        IsXValueIndexed = true,
    };

     Series series2 = new Series("seriesbar")
     {
        XValueType = ChartValueType.Date,    
        ChartArea = "ChartArea1",
        ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line,
        Legend = "Legend1",
        Name = "Gap",
        IsXValueIndexed = true,
        YAxisType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisType.Secondary,
        YValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Double
     };

    chart1.Series.Add(series1);
    chart1.Series.Add(series2);
    chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(797, 267);
    chart1.Text = "chart1";

    int[] dat = {20, 19, 10};
    for (int i = 0; i < dat.Length; i++ )
    {
        // Add X and Y values for a point. 
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Today.AddDays(i), dat[i]);
    }

    int[] dat2 = {20, 16, 12, 8, 4, 0};
    for (int i = 0; i < dat2.Length; i++ )
    {
        chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Today.AddDays(i), dat2[i]);
    }

    chart1.DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints(1, IntervalType.Days, "MyGraph, Gap");
    chart1.DataManipulator.IsEmptyPointIgnored  = true;
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(2048);
    chart1.SaveImage("C:\\temp\\chart.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, had to set.

```
chart1.Series[0].EmptyPointStyle.Color = Color.Transparent;
```

Also, I'd to remove the below property from the Series, this was interfering with the above style and was always drawing the point inspite of setting empty point color.

```
BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom,
```